# Bootstrap 3 select menus not selectable in sm or xs views

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When using bootstrap in a mobile view, select menus that appear on the same line are not selectable. It *could* have something to do with my bootstrap grid usage.

See my [codeply example here](http://www.codeply.com/go/N6b0dIKTJ8)

First try the select menus in the default desktop view.  Works fine.  Then toggle the screen size to tablet or smartphone and then the select menus.

Now, when the select menus appear on *different* lines, no problems in any view.  See this [codeply example](http://www.codeply.com/go/WAT9OTHwDI)

What am I missing here?  It's starting to drive me a bit crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On desktop screen(above bootstrap **md** screen size) you have one row with class *page-controls*, in which there are three cols:

- tools-sort (with class *col-md-3*)
- tools-paging (with class *col-md-2*)
- tools-pagination (with class *col-md-7*)

The total sum of columns grid is 12 and everything is fine.

The problem appears on non-desktop screen(below bootstrap **md** screen size) and you can inspect in the console that the third col *tools-pagination* expand on full width and it cover the two cols with the select menus, that's why they are not selectable.

The easiest way to fix this is to add additional grid col for smaller screens, for example:

```
<!-- Pagination and search controls -->
    <div id="ember1330" class="row page-controls ember-view">
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 pull-left tools-sort">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 pull-left tools-paging">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-7 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 text-right tools-paginaton">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
```

All I have added are the classes **col-sm-2** and **col-xs-6** to the cols with the two select boxes and the classes **col-sm-8** and **col-xs-12** to the pagination col.

This way the grid is fine on all mobile devices and the total sum of grid cols is 12 again on **sm** and on **xs** screens.

Comment: Ahhhh...that explains it!  Thanks SO MUCH for your help!

Comment: Glad to help you! :)